# Constructor.prototype not in the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, prototype

related: [Confusion about protype chain , primitives and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705232/369489)

in Firebug console :

```
a = 12
a.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a) // prints 'false'
```

I think this should print `true`

Answer (score 9):

`a = 12` creates a primitive number, which is not quite the same as a `Number` object. Primitives are implicitly cast to objects for purposes of property access.

```
a = 12; //a is a primitive
b = new Number(12); //b is an object
a.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a); //false because a is primitive
b.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(b); //true because b is an object
```

As per the [ECMAScript spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.6):

> When the `isPrototypeOf` method is called with argument *V*, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If *V* is not an object, return `false`.

primitive numbers are not, strictly speaking, objects.

Comment: Good answer.  This is further illustrated by `Object.getPrototypeOf(12)`, which throws `TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object`.  Whereas `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Number(12))` returns `Number {}`.

Comment: so if `a` is not an object, then why `a.constructor` works ??

Comment: @zzzzBov and jmar777.  Great explaination with sample code. Both Deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = new Number(12);
a.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a) // prints 'true'
```

I'm not smart enough to tell you why I just know that this is how it is. And yes, it's weird.

Now, you could say *"`12` is a primitive and `new Number(12)` is an object".* But how do you explain this?

```
(12).toFixed(3); // "12.000"
```

Apparently somewhere JavaScript is deciding the primitive might as well be an object.

Why does this distinction exist? How do you convert between the two forms? How does this impact performance? All questions related to this question that I don't have the answer to.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sure it doesn't but it's an interesting observation and it is indeed related to the question IMHO

Comment: @ashy_32bit, ...which makes it a comment, not an answer.

Comment: OP doesn't define the scope of his answer. He expects `true`, this is a way to get `true`.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see, you are completely right. But I still don't think this deserves a down vote, as a comment I would up vote it actually !

Comment: @FritsvanCampen perhaps you can put it in the comment form ?

Comment: I think the `(12).` causes an implicit conversion

Comment: This answer deserves an appreciation if not an upvote. Not a nice explaination but the demo code is quite nicely mentioned. Upvoted by me.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, primitives are defined in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) as not being objects, but for the purposes of accessing properties, and methods, they are temporarily cast to their respective object type.

Comment: @zzzzBov Perhaps that would make syntactic convenience but at the same time causes semantic confusion e.g. how come a primitive can have a constructor ?