# Confusion about prototype chain , primitives and objects

Tags: javascript, prototype, primitive

in firebug console :

```
>>> a=12 
12
>>> a.__proto__
Number {}
>>> (12).__proto__
Number {}
>>> a.constructor.prototype === (12).__proto__
true
>>> a.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)
false
```

the final line causes me a great confusion as compared to the other lines. also see [Constructor.prototype not in the prototype chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704682/constructor-prototype-not-in-the-prototype-chain/15704778#comment22302585_15704778)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `.` operator with a primitive, the language auto-boxes it with the appropriate Object type (in this case, Number). That's because simple primitive types in JavaScript really are not Object instances.

Thus, the actual left-hand side of

```
a.__proto__
```

is not the number `12` but essentially `new Number(12)`. However, the variable "a" continues to be the simple number value `12`.

*edit* — [Section 8.7 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) "explains" this with typical ECMA 262 moon language.  I can't find a clear paragraph that describes the way that a primitive *baseValue* is treated as a Number, Boolean, or String instance, but that section directly implies it.  I think that because those non-primitive synthetic values are ephemeral (they're only "real" while the `.` or `[]` expression is being evaluated) that the spec just talks about the behavior without explicitly requiring that an actual Number is constructed.  I'm guessing on that however.

Comment: would you be even kinder and perhaps give a reference to the ECMA specs for this conversion ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit updated, though what I could find in the spec is not very satisfying. It's a bunch of circular references between sections of the spec, none of which are particularly clear.

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy has explained it very well. Basically, if you want your last statement to be true, you would have to write it like:

```
a.constructor.prototype.isPrototypeOf(new Number(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript primitives do not have a prototype chain. Only objects do. A primitive value includes:

1. Booleans
2. Numbers
3. Strings
4. Null
5. Undefined

Hence if you call `isPrototypeOf` with a primitive value then it'll always return `false`.

If you try to use a boolean, number or string as an object then JavaScript automatically coerces it into an object for you. Hence `a.constructor` evaluates to `new Number(a).constructor` behind the scenes. This is the reason you can use a primitive value as an object.

If you wish to use a variable storing a primitive value as an object often then it's better to explicitly make it an object. For example in your case it would have been better to define `a` as `new Number(12)`. The advantages are:

1. JavaScript doesn't need to coerce the primitive to an object every time you try to use it as an object. You only create the object once. Hence it's performance efficient.
2. The `isPrototypeOf` method in your case will return `true` as `a` will be an instance of `Number`. Hence it will have `Number.prototype` in its prototype chain.