# Can not modify properties added to Number.prototype

Tags: javascript

Could somebody please explain this behavior in JavaScript?

```
var a = 6;
a.constructor.prototype.prop = 5;
print(a.prop);
a.prop = 4;
print(a.prop);
```

Then I run it in ideone:

```
5
5
```

I understand that `a` itself is a `number`, but its prorotype is `object`. But why such discrepancy exist? Surely this can be the source of multiple coding errors. Is this considered a "evil part" of JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is a primitive value. Not an object. You can only assign properties to objects. Not primitive values.

When you try to assign a property to a primitive value, JavaScript immediately coerces it to an object. For example:

```
var x = true; // x is primitive
x.y = false;  // x is coerced to an object
alert(x.y);   // y is undefined
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/UtYkA/

What's happening in the second line is:

```
new Boolean(x).y = false; // x is not the same as new Boolean(x)
```

Because `x` is coerced into an object and the property `y` is added to this object no property has been added to the `x` itself.

The same is true for all primitives - booleans, numbers and strings in JavaScript. This is the reason `print(a.prop)` always prints `5` - `a` is a primitive, not an object.

When you try to access `a.prop` it coerces `a` into an object but not the same object every time. Hence JavaScript treats it as follows:

```
var a = 6;
new Number(a).constructor.prototype.prop = 5;
print(new Number(a).prop);
new Number(a).prop = 4;    // assigning prop to an object which is discarded
print(new Number(a).prop); // accessing prop from an object which has no prop
```

For more information read the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705498/783743

Comment: Very concise! Thanks. `print((4).constructor.prototype === (new Number(5)).constructor.prototype);` outputs true exactly as you explained.

Comment: Would you call this coercing "boxing" as in other languages?

Comment: @ErikE - No. Coercion and boxing are two different concepts. For example in JavaScript `"2" - 1` is equal to `1`. Here the string (`"2"`) in being coerced into a number before subtracting `1` from it. In JavaScript one value (whether it's a primitive value or a reference value) may be coerced (automatically converted) into another value depending upon the context. For example the minus operator expects two numbers. Similarly the dot operator expects an object on the left hand side. Boxing on the other hand always converts a primitive value into a reference, and may or may not be implicit - C#.

Comment: Then how is a primitive coerced to an object if not by boxing?