# Why does a primitive variable act like an Object?

Tags: javascript

If we add a method to Number function (or Boolean or String) like this

```
Number.prototype.sayMyNumber = function(){
    return "My number is " + this;
}
```

and then create a number object assign it to a variable

```
var num1 = new Number(34); 
num1.sayMyNumber(); // it says "My number is 34"
```

This is fine and expected as we created 'Number' object.

Similarly, if I create a primitive variable

```
num2 = 34;
num2.sayMyNumber(); // it says "My number is 34"
```

Surprisingly, num2 also has a method sayMyNumber() even though we did not create a Number object explicitly.

Then I tried it like this,

```
34.sayMyNumber(); // error, this does not work
```

Why does num2 work?

**Update**

*This is a follow up question that I asked in the comment section, I am putting it here for better visibility*

Below answers mention that num2 is considered as a 'Number' object internally. This further confuses me.

```
typeof num1 === "number" // returns false
typeof num2 === "number" // returns true

typeof num1 === "object" // returns true
typeof num2 === "object" // returns false
```

Does this not mean that num2 is not an "object" ? 
If it is not an "object" then how can it be an instance of 'Number' ?

Comment: In `34.sayMyNumber()` dot is treated as **decimal point** which lead to error. You have to use parens if you want to force method invocation in this case. `num2` works cause any number in JS is `Number` instance even if it is defined as literal

Comment: It does not work even when I put it like this `(2).sayMyNumber()`. Not sure if this is the same as above

Comment: honestly (whatever_number).yourFunction() works

Comment: I just now double checked `(2).sayMyNumber()` does work

Comment: So far the answers say that num2 is also treated as an Number object, then why do they have different values for typeof

Comment: `34 .sayMyNumber()` :-)

Comment: A similar thing happens in Java called autoboxing. Whereby if you try to interact with a primitive type, the compiler will automatically wrap it in its associated wrapper class.

Comment: @Bergi The answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751704/javascript-do-primitive-strings-have-methods does not say why typeof gives a different value

Comment: @FlyingGambit: That's the problem with asking 3 different questions in one post :-) You might find further answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15704855/1048572) or [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33696067/1048572). Indeed, `num2` is not an object. It only gets implicitly converted to one when a property lookup is done on it.

Answer (score 4):

The primitive type *Number* has a corresponding object representation, which you can create with `new Number`. This is an *object* and is therefore of a different *data type* than the primitive type *Number*.

If you call `Number(34)` (without `new`) an object isn't created, but the Number function performs a type conversion, to a primitive number value.

```
var num1 = new Number(34); // object
var num2 = 34; // primitive
```

When you call `sayMyNumber()` on the primitive number `num2`, JavaScript internally converts the primitive temporarily to its equivalent object version. And because you added `sayMyNumber()` to `Number.prototype` you have access to the function.

The reason `34.sayMyNumber()` doesn't work is because when JavaScript engine parses your source code, it has to interpret just what a dot means in a given context. In the case of `34.sayMyNumber()` the dot is potentially ambiguous. Does it mean the decimal separator? Or does it mean object member access? JavaScript opts to interpret all integers followed by a dot as representing part of a floating point number. But as there is no such number 34.sayMyNumber(), it raises a SyntaxError. [Read more here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/numbers-and-javascripts-dot-notation.html)

Comment: How can they be same when  typeof is different `typeof num1 = "object"` and  `typeof num2 = "number"`

Comment: Didn't you mean `var num1 = Number(34)`. A `Number` is not an object so `new` does not make sense.

Comment: You are right @doug65536. I just copied OP's code line and didn't think of `new`.

Comment: @doug65536 Number is a native function with dual behaviour `typeof (Number(34)) is "number"` and `typeof (new Number(34)) is "object"`. We wanted to make comparison between primitive and object, hence the use of new

Comment: _34.sayMyNumber(); is a syntax error. A variable cant start with a number._ Wrong explanation. There is **no variable**, that is an **expression** which obviously _may start with a number_. The real cause is different (wrong meaning of dot symbol)

Comment: Thanks @hindmost, have fixed it.

Comment: Also frankly I don't understand how exactly that quote from MDN (about loosely typed language) can lead to conclusion that definitions by number literal and `Number` constructor are the same.

Comment: `34` or `Number(34)` is not a Number instance - it's not an object. I can't inherit from `Number.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain why? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/prototype) says **All Number instances inherit from Number.prototype**

Comment: @swenedo, how does 34.blahblah treated as decimal? It suppose to be a syntax or illegal statement.

Comment: @SathikKhan When a JavaScript engine parses your source code, it has to interpret just what a dot means in a given context. In the case of `34.sayMyNumber()` the dot is potentially ambiguous. Does it mean the decimal separator? Or does it mean object member access? JavaScript opts to interpret all integers followed by a dot as representing part of a floating point number. But as there is no such number `34.sayMyNumber()`, it raises a SyntaxError. [Read more here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/numbers-and-javascripts-dot-notation.html)

Comment: @swenedo: As I said, `34` or `Number(34)` are no Number *instances* (objects), they're primitive *numbers*.

Comment: @Bergi Yes but `34` and `Number(34)` get converted to a Number instance when `.sayMyNumber()` is called, and they get access to the the the function OP added to `Number.prototype`... Hmm.. I should probably read up on this again, I'm a little bit confused now :)

Comment: Yes, this implicit conversion is important, you should focus your answer on it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I have done some reading, and think it is correct now :)

Comment: how do you explain num2.toString()?

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript coerces between primitives and objects. In this case the number value is coerced to a `Number` object in order to access the prototype method `sayMyNumber`. Actually, in this way primitives have access to all the properties and methods defined by their respective object constructors. However, they are different from the objects as they are immutable.

Thus, `(34).sayMyNumber();` works; so does `(34).toFixed()` or `(34).toPrecision()`.

As for `34.sayMyNumber();`, as hindmost pointed out, is a syntax error.

Comment: Numbers surely are not treated like objects.

Answer (score -4):

For both,

```
var num1 = new Number(34); 
num2 = 34;
```

You are assigning `"Number"` type values to both `num1` and `num2` variables. So it calls the prototype, which attached to the `"Number"`.

But calling `34.sayMyNumber` has syntax error and its an illegal statement.

If anyone has question on this please refer... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: Can someone explain why downvotes? I will fix if something wrong here...

Comment: `num1` and `num2` do have different types.

Comment: I have mentioned type values... And mozillaa says "The numeric value of the object being created...  "   new Number(value);
    If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN.
    In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number...